# is there a way to edit multiple lines of text in text wrangler

Tags: textwrangler

I have opened a csv file in TextWrangler and need to add a few characters to the end of all of the cells.  Is there a way to do this without having to copy/paste these characters on each line separately? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file has this format:

```
Name,Address,Age
Mr. Foo,"123 Anywhere St, Billings, MN 12345",42
Miss Bar,"234 Somewhere Else Rd, Springfield, TX 98764",99
```

The easiest and fastest way to append text onto these lines would be to use the `$` character. If you know that you will enter two more fields: `Gender` and `Hobbies`, and those fields are all the same (you don't need different values for each entry), you can simply replace lines 2..n with

```
Search:
$

Replace:
,Male,"Cats,Riding Bikes,Chasing cars"
```

You would need to provide more information in your question for more detailed help, though. The best is to give example input and what your desired results would look like.